# Scala play-silhouette 2.0 - update user password

Tags: scala, playframework, silhouette

I'm using `play-silhouette v2.0` plugin to manage authentication in my `play2/scala` application. I would like to know how to handle the password update for a user. I can't find any docs/example on that.

The only example I found is [this](https://github.com/adrianhurt/play-multidomain-auth/blob/master/modules/admin/app/controllers/Auth.scala) but it is referred to version 3.0

Comment: What's the problem? I ask because the update of the password isn't really a part of the Silhouette library itself. If you register a user then the `CredentialsProvider` stores the `PasswordInfo` in the database. To change the password you must update the `PasswordInfo` in the database. The `CredentialsProviders` updates the password itself if the password hasher changes. So it shows how you can update the password in the database with Silhouette means. https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/blob/2.0.1/silhouette/app/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/impl/providers/CredentialsProvider.scala#L69

Comment: I was asking because I couldn't find the equivalent of this [call](https://github.com/adrianhurt/play-multidomain-auth/blob/master/modules/admin/app/controllers/Auth.scala#L203) in silhouette 2.0.
Following your suggestion, I added a new `update` method to my `PasswordInfoDAO` and I use that to update the password data. It works greatly. Thanks